# Make Different Borders for Card in Material UI in React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to have different kind of borders depending on the condition.
This seems not to work? The border doesn't appear.

```
<Card
  key={key}
  elevation={0}
  sx={{
    borderWidth:
      errorMessages?.length ||
      (productImage?.status === 'Linked' && productExistingAndLinked) ||
      (productImage.status === 'Existing' && productExistingAndLinked) ||
      (!isTrustMeCheck && productImage.status === 'Existing')
        ? '3px'
        : '1px',
    borderColor: errorMessages?.length
      ? `solid error.main`
      : productImage?.status === 'Linked' && productExistingAndLinked
      ? `solid success.main`
      : productImage?.status === 'Existing' && productExistingAndLinked
      ? `solid error.main`
      : !isTrustMeCheck && productImage.status === 'Existing'
      ? `solid error.main`
      : `solid`,
    borderRadius: '8px',
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    maxHeight: 'max-content',
  }}
> ....
</Card>
```

Comment: Nested ternary operators should be avoided. You can make separate functions that'll return borderWidth and borderColor based on your given condition.

Answer (score 0):

You can write two separate functions that'll return borderWidth and borderColor and then call from sx props.

```
// get border width
function getBorderWidth(){
  
    if (errorMessages?.length || 
      (productImage?.status === 'Linked' && productExistingAndLinked) ||
      (productImage.status === 'Existing' && productExistingAndLinked) ||
      (!isTrustMeCheck && productImage.status === 'Existing')
      ) {
        return '3px';
      }

      return '1px';
}


// get border color
function getBorderColor() {
  if (errorMessages?.length) {
    return 'solid error.main';
  } else if (productImage?.status === 'Linked' && productExistingAndLinked) {
    return 'solid success.main';
  } else if (productImage?.status === 'Existing' && productExistingAndLinked) {
    return 'solid error.main';
  } else if (!isTrustMeCheck && productImage.status === 'Existing') {
    return 'solid error.main';
  }

  return 'solid';
}
```

and finally call the two functions to get width and color

```
sx = {{
...
borderWidth: getBorderWidth(),
borderColor: getBorderColor(),
...
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply your border width or color like below as style

```
style={{borderColor:"white!important"}}
```

Dont forget use important tag